# Matlab classregtree with multidimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, gesture-recognition

For some gesture recognition software I want to build a recognition tree using the matlab function classregtree.

When I have a binary image of only the gesture, I create 2 intensity spectra: one for the x-axis and one for the y-axis. From these spectra I want to extract some data, and use that to build the classregtree. Examples of the data I use are the width of the spectrum, the number of spikes, and the total area of the gesture. However, I also want to use data which has a variable number of parameters: e.g. I want to use the heights of the individual spikes in the spectrum too as parameters for the classregtree. However, classregtree requires a fixed number of doubles for every dataset, while the number of spikes, and therefore the number of variables I want to pass, is variable. What is the best way to use this data? I could just use a fixed number of parameters and pass a value of 0 if I can't create a value (e.g. I always pass the values of 10 spikes, but when I have less than 10 their values will be 0), but I'm afraid that it won't work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A usual way to deal with your problem is to make histograms. The nice property of histograms is that they always have the same size.

So for instance you could make a histogram of the heights of your spikes (with fixed binning), using `histc`.

Comment: So that's essentially passing 0 values for every value which isn't found right? Because if a value is not found we get an empty bin. By the way, I forgot to tell, but the number of spikes is quite small (usually below 10), but the spreading of values is quite large, but very important. So if I create a histogram, I'll probably get just bins with values 0 and 1.

Comment: Not really, this is much different. For instance, if you have two signals [0.1 0.9 0.1 0.9] and [0.1 0.1]. With your formulation, they would be described by [0.1 0.9 0.1 0.9] and [ 0.1 0.1 0 0]. With th histograms (let's say three bins [0 1/3 2/3 1]), the representation will be [2 0 2] and [ 2 0 0 ]

Comment: But in my situations 2 values will rarely be near the same value. So a set of [0.1 0.9 0.1 0.9] will probably not happen. The signals will be more like [0.1 0.4 0.9] or something, and if I group 2 of these values together, the results will change too much. But I might be able to use differences of values (should've thought of that before), since those can be grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that filling in with arbitrary values (such as zeros) will not work well.  If you can tell reasonably reliably how many spikes there are, and there's enough data, then you might try constructing separate tree for each number of spikes.